# Why label's height is zero?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, uilabel, snapkit

```
contentLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = kScreenWidth - 20
contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

I use SnapKit to set top and left.

```
 contentLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
  make.top.equalTo(topView.snp.bottom)
  make.left.equalTo(topView.iconView)
}
print(contentLabel.frame.size.height)
```

It prints 0. Does it all right?

Answer (score 1):

you can get label height by this function in Swift 3:

```
func GetheightOfLable(strLable:String , widthlable:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{

    let rectDetail:CGRect = strLable.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: widthlable, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontSize], context: nil)
    print(rectDetail.height)
    return rectDetail.height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,i think it will help you

```
let sizeToFit = CGSize(width: contentLabel.frame.size.width,
                       height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
let textSize = contentLabel.sizeThatFits(sizeToFit)
```

Hope it will help you